# Resharper hotkey not working Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have installed ReSharper Ultimate (2015.1.1) for  Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. The .Net Framework version is 4.5.51650. ReSharper hotkey Ctrl+T etc...  not work in my Visual Studio. Thank for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reapply the ReSharper shortcuts in ReSharper → Options → Keyboard & menus → Apply Scheme. Make sure you have the appropriate scheme selected - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> implies you're after the Visual Studio scheme, select this before hitting Apply.